# Expanded variable values in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am learning some basics of Makefile, and write simple example as below:

```
urname=Chang
givenname=SJ
fullname=$(givenname) $(surname)
hello:
    @echo $(fullname)

surname=Lin

ALL_PACKAGES=
hello1:
ifeq (,$(ALL_PACKAGES))
    @echo There is no package
    $(error $(ALL_PACKAGES) is empty)
else
    @echo there are some packages
endif
    @echo $(ALL_PACKAGES)

ALL_PACKAGES += package1
```

I can understand `make hello` result will be "SJ Lin", cause $(surname) is "Lin" finally.

However, in result of `make hello1`,why $(ALL_PACKAGES) is empty in the if condition(I guess if will be "package1" in the same way on `make hello`)?

Moreover, why the first echo message("There is no package") will not be printed but only error message do?

Thanks teachers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `make hello` will yield "Jay Lin", not "SJ Lin".  I don't know where you got "SJ" from.
2. `ALL_PACKAGES` is empty at that point in the parsing, so that's why you get that result.  The `ifeq` is handled at the time of parsing the makefile, before it actually starts to run and build targets.
3. The error message prints out (and causes `make` to exit) while it is parsing the makefile, before it starts to run and build targets.
4. If you were to comment out the `$(error` line, you'll get two printouts from `make hello1` - both the `There is no package` message (included because of the state of `ALL_PACKAGES` at that point in the parsing), and then also `package1`, from `$(ALL_PACKAGES)` being expanded later, during the actual `make` processing.

Comment: Then, the ifeq will compare $(ALL_PACKAGES) just like ALL_PACKAGE:= but not the finally expanded $(ALL_PACKAGES), right?